# Calling a function with a variable input in Python

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm really new to python, and I'm having trouble with the code

```
def even(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return "Even"
    else:
        return "Odd"

one = input("Number: ")
print(even(one))
```

I want it to ask the user for a number, then print if it's even or odd, but every time I execute the program and type in a number it gives me an error. Any ideas on what I'm missing or doing wrong? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to turn 'one' to int ( `int(one)` )

Comment: The input always take the input as an string. Try to convert it to integer first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) returns `str` object and you are trying to act with it like it has type `int`, just cast user input

```
one = int(input("Number: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code run without problem in `python2.x`.  In `python3.x`, you need to update your code to this

```
def even(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return "Even"
    else:
        return "Odd"

one = int(input("Number: ")) # here is the update
print(even(one))
```

[related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20449433/1099230) on intput

Comment: It should be mentioned, that `input` on Python 2 will lead to severe security problems. So the code for Python 2 should look like: `one = int(raw_input("Number: "))`